# Compiz Magnifier Box doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, compiz, shortcut-keys, effects

I have upgraded my ubuntu to 12.10 and installed CompizConfig Setting Manager to do some custom settings and one of the is enabling Magnifier Box. But this doesn't work, i have tried many shortcut combination but it still does't work.

Is there any compatibility issue with this feature or what? please let me know if there is a trick or an issue.

The Magnifier Box will magnify some area withing the box or with an image overlay.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to be presented with the same window. Check the general tab and see what it holds. Possibly try checking for updates to the application as well. My window is as below:

[image: CompizConfig Settings Screenshot (Enhanced Zoom Desktop Screen)]

I managed to set it to zoom in but I wasn't presented with a box to show the zoom contents, my entire screen zooms into the area around the cursor.

Setting "Zoom out" action as Ctrl + D and the Zoom Box action as Shift + Right Mouse Click gives:
 - Holding Shift and left clicking will zoom into the area around the cursor.
 - Holding Ctrl + tapping D will zoom out at a steady pace to allow to be less zoomed 
   or
  - Hold Ctrl + D to zoom out entirely.

Of course you can set the Zoom factor to be greater or less to zoom into your required level automatically.